# Mount Linux host directory inside QEMU FreeBSD guest

Tags: freebsd, qemu, libvirt

I am managing a few FreeBSD 11 QEMU guests on a Linux host (kernel: 4.9). I would like to mount a directory from the Linux host into the FreeBSD guest. I have done a similar thing with Linux guests using this [method](http://rabexc.org/posts/p9-setup-in-libvirt). It seems that I need to have the right virtio modules for FreeBSD. From what I gather, 9pnet is not available for the FreeBSD, so perhaps there is a analogous module that I could use.

Comment: I don't think i's possible, as "filesystem passthrough" in libvirt uses the 9p kernel module. An alternative way would be to use NFS server on the host and NFS client on the guest.